# How to get the direct children of a specified tag in xml using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, children, xml-documentation

Please check the below code. I need to check only the children that are defined inside the parent tag.

If any unexpected child appears in that parent I need to report that as error.

This is my XML File:

```
<places>
  <Tirunelveli>XXXX</Tirunelveli>//allowed child of places
  <Tiruchendur></Tiruchendur>//allowed child of places
  <Alwar></Alwar>//allowed child of places
  <sweet></sweet>//not allowed child of places and i have to report this tag as error
</places>
```

I need to check that the `<places>` parent only has child tags that are allowed. Otherwise I need to add it as an error.

```
var rd = new FileReader();
rd.onload = function(e){  
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.result);                   
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
//check allowed child of front tag
check_allowed_direct_child("places", "Tirunelveli,Tiruchendur,Alwar", "RULE_002", "Fail");                  

//Function to check the x tag have only the alowed child y
function check_allowed_direct_child(x,y,rule,error_type)
{
    var child_array = y.split(',');
    var child_count=child_array.length;
    var ischild=""
    var xmlchild="";
    $xml.children(x).each(function()
    {
        ischild="no";
        xmlchild=this.value;
        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
        if(child_array[i]==xmlchild)
        {
            ischild="yes";
        }
        }
        if(ischild=="no")
        {
            //count the total error and warnings
            check_total_error_warning(error_type);
            $("#validation_report").append('<tr class="err"><td><a href="Asset\Rules\Rule.html\#'+rule+'">'+rule+'</td><td><span class="highlight">&#x0003C;'+xmlchild+'&#x0003E;</span> is not allowed inside the <span class="highlight">&#x0003C;'+x+'&#x0003E;</span> element</td><td class="'+classname+'">'+error_type+'</td></tr>');
            }

            });
            }

};rd.readAsText(this.files[i]);
```

But the `children()` code is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is *aa*, is it an element that is valid to the `.children()` function? I.e. the parent element of the children that you are iterating through? `$('#'+x).children('selector').each(function () { //code goes here }`. Here I'm appending x (your parent element) to an *id* selector (if it's an id that's being used, I don't know, since you haven't added your HTML). If you want more precise answers, I suggest adding the relevant HTML.

Comment: @Martin i added some detail to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you select the parent node needs correction: use `find` to locate it, then use `children` on that result (without argument) to get all the children.

If the parent node is the root of the XML, then `find` will not find it, but with `addBack` you can also include the root node in the match.

I would also use camelCase for your function names, and use jQuery functions to build dynamic HTML.

Here is how that could look:

```js
var $xml = $("<aa><bb></bb><cc></cc><dd></dd><ee></ee></aa>");
var className = "someClass"
 
//check allowed child of front tag
checkChildAllowed($xml, "aa", ["bb","cc","dd"], "RULE_002", "Fail");                   

//Function to check the x tag have only the allowed child y
function checkChildAllowed($xml, parent, allowedChildren, rule, errorType) {
    // Make sure to first locate the parent correctly:
    var $parent = $xml.find(parent).addBack(parent); 
    // Uppercase tag names as jQuery uses that HTML convention
    allowedChildren = allowedChildren.map(childName => childName.toUpperCase()); 
    $parent.children().each(function () {
        if (allowedChildren.includes(this.nodeName)) return; // tag is OK
        // Include this if that function is defined:
        //check_total_error_warning(error_type); 
        $("#validation_report").append( // Use jQuery functions
            $("<tr>").addClass("err").append(
                $("<td>").append(
                    $("<a>").attr("href", "Asset\Rules\Rule.html\#"+rule).text(rule)
                ),
                $("<td>").append(
                    $("<span>").addClass("highlight")
                               .text("<"+this.nodeName.toLowerCase()+">"),
                    " is not allowed inside the ",
                    $("<span>").addClass("highlight").text("<"+parent+">"),
                    " element"
                ),
                $("<td>").addClass(className).text(errorType)
            )
        );
    });
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td { border: 1px solid; padding: 5px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="validation_report"></table>
```

Comment: is it possible get the line number of the child <ee> in xml using JQUERY

Comment: Not the line number directly, but the sequence number of the child: see [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method in jQuery documentation. You could take it further and calculate the size of each node that comes before the match and get a character offset out of that, but that is already more elaborate to do...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is that you loop through your child elements of your parent element of your choice. Your parent element in this case is *"places"*.

You can the use the javascript function `.tagName` to get the element type of the child. You can then construct a condition around that to check for the allowed / disallowed child(ren).

Example:

```js
var rd = new FileReader();
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.result);                   
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
var classname='errorClass';

function check_allowed_direct_child(x="places",
        y="Tirunelveli,Tiruchendur,Alwar",
                                    rule="RULE_002",
                                    error_type="Fail") {
    var notAllowedChild='sweet';
    var child_array=y.split(",");
    for(i=0; child_array.length > i; i++) {
        if(child_array[i] != notAllowedChild) {
     alert(child_array[i]+' is an allowed child');
 }
    }
    $(''+x).children().each(function () {
        var elements=this.tagName.toLowerCase();
 if(elements == notAllowedChild) {
     alert(elements+' is not an allowed child');
            $("#validation_report").append('<tr class="err"><td><a href="#">'+rule+'</td><td><span class="highlight">&#x0003C;'+elements+'&#x0003E;</span> is not allowed inside the <span class="highlight">&#x0003C;'+x+'&#x0003E;</span> element</td><td class="'+classname+'">'+error_type+'</td></tr>');
 }
    });
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<places>
  <Tirunelveli>XXXX</Tirunelveli>
  <Tiruchendur></Tiruchendur>
  <Alwar></Alwar>
  <sweet></sweet>
</places>
<table id="validation_report"></table>
<br />
<button onclick="check_allowed_direct_child();">Test</button>
```